# Laravel 5 | Login using multiple identifiers

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I would like to let a user login by providing his/her

- username
- or email id (of the few available)
- or phone number

along with password, similar to how it works in Facebook and LinkedIn.

What is the best/elegant way to achieve this using Laravel 5.2 default Authentication?

Comment: you can just further develop (extend) the default authentication

Comment: I guess. Just was wondering if there was an extension/ better way to do it.

Comment: no extension as far as I know, and the best way is to do your own, otherwise you need to use 3rd party authentication

Comment: I guess so. I'd answer this question with code I've written then.

Comment: Sure you go a head and present your solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no 3rd party solution available up to my knowledge.
here is my working example that how I am doing it... this `postLogin` some sample code.

```
$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

$credentials_username   =   ['username'=>$credentials['username'], 'password'=>$credentials['password']];
$credentials_email      =   ['email'=>$credentials['username'], 'password'=>$credentials['password']];
$credentials_phone      =   ['phone'=>$credentials['username'], 'password'=>$credentials['password']];

//adedd custom, we also want to check by username too
if (Auth::attempt($credentials_email, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);

//also check for the username if exists then login to the system    
}elseif (Auth::attempt($credentials_username, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);

//also check for phone no     
}elseif (Auth::attempt($credentials_phone, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
}
```